# Getting the text() from an element or sub-element

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working on the following [document](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/source/docbook/part06/part06.xml) (using `<xsl:apply-templates select="*/*/dk:table[@xml:id='table_6-1']" />`). I need to extract the `text()` from either:

```
<para>
<emphasis role="italic">(0008,0001)</emphasis>
</para>
```

or (simply):

```
<para>(0008,0005)</para>
```

What I came up with (XSLT 1.0 only please) is the following (full script [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/malaterre/GDCM/master/Source/DataDictionary/Part6.xsl)):

```
<xsl:variable name="vm">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="dk:td[1]/dk:para/dk:emphasis">
      <xsl:value-of select="dk:td[1]/dk:para/dk:emphasis/text()"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="dk:td[1]/dk:para/text()"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

I find it very ugly, and very cumbersome, is there any other (simplier) way ?

Comment: Yes, `<xsl:value-of select="dk:td[1]/dk:para/dk:emphasis/text()"/>` is cumbersome but can at least be shortened to `<xsl:value-of select="dk:td[1]/dk:para/dk:emphasis"/>`. As for the general problem, it is not clear what determines which element you want to select, you say either/or and show two elements with different `xml:id` attributes, are these relevant? Can the input have both type of elements? Which one do you want?

Comment: I removed the `xml:id` since I am not using them at this level

Comment: Why not just write templates for text() and dk:emphasis in the normal way?

Comment: I second the advice of @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen . In fact, as can be seen in my answer, it isn't even necessary to write any new template, because the XSLT built-in templates do exactly what is wanted in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Just use**:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select=
                     "dk:td[1]/dk:para/dk:emphasis | dk:td[1]/dk:para[not(dk:emphasis)]"/>
```

**Explanation**:

This selects the XSLT built-in template for elements, on any `dk:td[1]/dk:para/dk:emphasis` element and any `dk:td[1]/dk:para[not(dk:emphasis)]` elements. The last match-pattern means: any `dk:td[1]/dk:para` element that doesn't have a `dk:emphasis` child.

The action of the built-in template is to output the concatenation of all text-node descendents of the current node -- in this case the element has a single child text node -- so exactly this is output.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the input it might suffice to simply use `<xsl:variable name="vm" select="normalize-space(dk:td[1]/dk:para)"/>`. That would select the same value for both input snippets you have shown, namely the string value `(0008,0001)`.

I don't know however if your input data can have white space (e.g. `<para>abc   efg</para>`) you need to preserve, using the suggested approach the variable would then hold the string `abc efg`.

If you use `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` or `<xsl:strip-space elements="dk:td"/>` then both input samples would result in a para element with the same string value so you could then even use `<xsl:variable name="vm" select="dk:td[1]/dk:para"/>` and any white space in the data (like my sample `<para>abc   efg</para>` would be preserved.

I would never use an explicit `text()` selection in XSLT/XPath anyway unless I need to deal with mixed contents (or know I am using some particular API like some Python XPath APIs where an explicit `text()` selection then gives you back a smart string instead of an text node).